# I want .orderBy('Name', descending: false) close no problem but open it error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want .orderBy('Name', descending: false) close no problem but open it error.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: (name != '' && name != null)
        ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('BeeBox')
            .where("Idfarm", isEqualTo: widget.idFram)
            .where("Name", isEqualTo: name)
            .snapshots()
        : FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("BeeBox")
            .where("Idfarm", isEqualTo: widget.idFram)
            .orderBy('Name', descending: false)
            .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                return Container(child: ListTile(
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  // beeboxModels[index].name ?? 'กำลังโหลด',
                  data['Name'],
                  style: GoogleFonts.sarabun(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              // beeboxModels[index].location ?? 'กำลังโหลด',
              data['LocationName'],
              style: GoogleFonts.sarabun(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                fontSize: 13,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
          ),);
               },
            );
    },
  ),
```

TERMINAL:

> W/Firestore(29683): integer_value: 0
>
> W/Firestore(29683): string_value: "W4i9SnmR7lyoL0fc33TB" order by Name, **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/bee-app-65be5/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ckxwcm9qZWN0cy9iZWUtYXBwLTY1YmU1L2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9CZWVCb3gvaW5kZXhlcy9fEAEaCgoGSWRmYXJtEAEaCAoETmFtZRABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE, cause=null}
> I/flutter (29683): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'docs' was called on null.
> I/FirebaseAuth(29683): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
> W/System  (29683): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says: the query you're trying to perform requires that you explicitly create a composite index for it. If you click the URL in the error message, it will take you to the Firebase console with all values pre-populated to create that index.

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help.